# Connecting on a sip socket

Tags: java, sockets, sip

I'm trying to connect on a sip socket, like this :

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.190"), 5060);
```

But I've got an exception : "failed to connect to /192.168.1.190 (port 5060): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (connection refused)

Do I have to put some connection informations? But where?

Comment: i think no one is listening in 5060 change port

Comment: are you even creaing a connection to that port